# Hide number inside image

Tags: steganography

I'm wanting to hide a six digit number inside an image. I know various steganography methods such as changing the LSB, however, I am wanting the code to be able to be decoded when you take a picture of that image.

I have heard of Digimarc, however I am not interested in using that.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for ? Some code, software ? In what language ? Have you already try something ?

Comment: I'm looking either for some code OR a steering in the right direction, I don't need software, thanks.

Comment: here is an example with Java code: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/27950-steganography/

Comment: That one I've looked at before, and that wouldn't work when taking an image of the encoded image. Let me explain it a little clearer, I'm looking to encode a number in an image, and then take a picture of it on a mobile device which will then decode it.

Comment: Look at how qr codes work maybe? Provide a color range for each bit you encode so the mobile picture doesn't change it too much?